# on scrolling in listview get force close

Tags: android, android-listview

i write a code in onScrollStateChanged event of listview .
but when scroll changed fast, get force close .

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
try {
int getCur = (lstName.getLastVisiblePosition() + 1) % maxName;
if (myCR != null) {
if (getCur == 0) {
Parcelable state = lstName.onSaveInstanceState();
fillList();

lstName.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
}
}
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Completed Logcat :

```
http://up.persianscript.ir/uploads/137181658700741.zip
```

Comment: Are you sure lstName is not null? It would be nice to have more clarification

Comment: in fillList, i set adapter of listview .

Comment: It seems that the crash doesn't come from _onScrollStateChanged_ but from the adapter of your ListView. Is the logcat error complete?

Comment: completed logcat  is : http://up.persianscript.ir/uploads/137181658700741.zip